# how to play sound on incoming calls

Tags: iphone

My client wants to play a sound for particular numbers for incoming call.So
I want to play a sound on particular number for incoming calls,
Please, help how can I solve this problem?
Means  user should hear that sound or , can I reduce the signal quality when that number callS?
or simply how can stop unwanted calls?

Comment: Is that a programming question? I mean, you're not allowed to do much on the iPhone about the telephony part, so you're mostly confined to settings on the default stuff.

Comment: I want that using my app.So I need to confirm that is it possible in IOS Programming

Comment: Are you targetting jailbroken iOS, enterprise distribution or AppStore?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't then. Probably need undocumented APIs and other forbidden features by Apple's rules.

Comment: can you refer such api please

Comment: see i need to play a sound for user after attending the call, is it possible?

Comment: "Reduce signal quality"? Sounds like your client wants to fake "being in a tunnel" so he doesn't have to talk to particular people (wife? lol).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the ringtone for that particular number?